# Usage of Jitsi Video Call and Natario Cameraview Simultaneously

Tags: android, session, android-activity, android-camera, jitsi-meet

In my android application, I use Jitsi meet video call in the first activity and natario cameraview in the second. The aim is to switch to the other activity with a button and read the user's ID card while the video call is taking place. But jitsi doesn't share camera resource with cameraview object, so I see black screen on natario cameraview side. I wish Jitsi side had a black screen because I'm doing ID reading in activity 2 and the camera is a must.
So is there a way to get the camera from jitsi? Maybe with camera sessions.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution after 1 mount, I hope this answer will help someone in the feature. Its very simple.

When you want to close Jitsi camera just use  `JitsiMeetActivityDelegate.onHostPause(MainActivityJitsi.this);`

and when you want to open it call

```
 JitsiMeetActivityDelegate.onHostResume(MainActivityJitsi.this);
```

These codes will just close the camera not sound. And conferance will be countinue dont worry :).